# Can anyone ID this ant queen species?

Tags: species-identification, entomology, ant, classification

[image]

[image]

It was found in Hong Kong! Below are a few basic information:

Place: Hong Kong

Habitat: Forest. I live very close to a mountain with lots of forestation.

Where Collected: Found it in my window slit of my apartment.

Coloration: Major body parts are black, but legs are light brown.

Distinguishing characteristics: Appears to have one spine in the mid-body (not sure); Huge mandibles

Length: 14mm to 15mm

Width: 3mm

Anything else distinctive: It could move incredibly fast (like a cockroach). Also, it appears to be quite aggressive. When I put in an ant (male ant with wings) of a different species to its tube, it attacked the introduced ant with its mandibles immediately. During its attack, it shook its abdomen periodically.

Answer (score 5):

The species in the photo is a carpenter ant (*Camponotus irritans*), possibly *C. i. hongkongensis*. More info, photos, and video [here](https://alchetron.com/Camponotus-irritans).

Comment: Also, it's a worker, not a queen.

Comment: No it is a queen (broad thorax and abdomen) hence the eggs.

Comment: The thorax and gastor (abdomen) are actually typical of Camponotus workers. Also, the presence of eggs is not solely evidence that it is a queen; worker ants frequently carry eggs to and from the nest.